# django find user organization by user uid

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I'm trying to get user organization by user uid.
I have an `Organization` model with the user field as ForeignKey(User) and I have the user UID,
Is there any way to find the `organization` by the uid without querying out the user id by the uid and then finding the organization by the id?

`

```
        user_uid = "some uid"
        user= User.objects.get(uid=uid)
        Organization.objects.filter(user=user)
```

`

> how can I avoid two queries?

Comment: Organization.objects.filter(user__uid= user_uid)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Organization.objects.filter(user__uid=uid)
```